# wait for promise in loop

Tags: javascript, async-await

I got this function:

```
const upload = (example) => {
    console.log('uploading...');
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve & reject
    });
};
```

I call the function above here:

```
const dirents = await fs.readdirSync(path, {withFileTypes:true});
await Promise.all(dirents.map(async (dirent) => {
    await upload(example).then((response) => {
        console.log('success');
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

The output should be

```
'uploading' -> 'success' -> 'uploading' ...
```

But it is actually

```
'uploading' -> 'uploading' -> 'success' -> 'success'
```

I also tried (`for ... of`) but it doesn't work for me neither.

Comment: Promise.all doesn't call sequentially. It just waits for all to resolve. They get started at the same time

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel why does it not work with (for ... of) neither?

Comment: You probably didn't await the previous upload before starting the next one

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel I used the same code as above, just with (for ... of)

Comment: There are endless possibilities to convert this to for of

Comment: `await upload(example).then(`  that's illogical code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a modern example using `reduce` with `async/ await` (which you can run [here](https://es6console.com/jqzjqzvn/))

```
let userIDs = [1,2,3];

userIDs.reduce( async (previousPromise, nextID) => {
  await previousPromise;
  return upload(nextID).then((val) => {
    console.log("success", val);
  })
}, Promise.resolve());


const upload = (id) => {
    console.log('uploading...', id);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(id);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

For sequential promises, using a simple loop in an `async` function is very clear and readable:

```js
let userIDs = [1, 2, 3];

async function uploadIDS(ids) {
  for (let id of ids) {
    let res = await upload(id)
    console.log("Success:", res)
  }
}

const upload = (example) => {
  console.log('uploading...');
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(example)
  });
};

uploadIDS(userIDs)
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can do it also, with Recursion function **

```
 //const dirents = await fs.readdirSync(path, {withFileTypes:true});

    const dirents = [1,2,3]


    const upload = (example) => {
        console.log('uploading...');
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve(example)
        });
    };

    function callUpload(dirent, length, count) {

        if(count >= dirents.length){
            return;
        }
        upload(dirent).then(() => {
            count += 1;
            console.log("success")
            callUpload(dirents[count], dirents.length, count)
        })
    }
    callUpload(dirents[0], dirents.length, 0)
```